# Not able to load image file in jsp of spring mvc and not getting alternate text for image

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm not able to load image file in jsp of my spring mvc application..My directory structure and code is as fallows..I'm even not able to get alternate text for image.. Please help me..

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.imr.smsapp.web"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:resources  mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/images/,/resources/css/,/resources/pages/"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
<property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="mappingResources">
<list>
<value>com/imr/smsapp/model/Address.hbm.xml</value>
<value>com/imr/smsapp/model/Student.hbm.xml</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" 
class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
<value>/WEB-INF/views/student/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="studentDaoImpl" class="com.imr.smsapp.dao.Impl.StudentDaoImpl"/>
<bean id="studentServiceImpl" class="com.imr.smsapp.service.Impl.StudentServiceImpl"/>
</beans>
```

**In form.jsp**

```
</form:form>
<img  src="<c:url value="/resources/imgaes/random_number.png"/>" alt="Image alternate Text">
</body>
```

If I use  src="/resources/imgaes/random_number.png"  in the above code in my jsp I'm able to see the image in jsp editor preview but not getting displayed when I run my app..

images are in the fallowing path  webroot/resources/images/...

Comment: What if you remove the "/resources" from the beginning?

Comment: I tried that one too.. but didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed. I modified the image tag code to

```
<img  src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/random_number.png" alt="Image alternate Text">
```

Can anyone explain the reason why the previous methods didn't work for me..